# tf.train.batch( allow_smaller_final_batch=True, ) does not shape batch correctly

Tags: tensorflow

If I use `tf.train.batch( allow_smaller_final_batch=True, )` the shape of the tensor is unknown:

`allow_smaller_final_batch=True`: Tensor shape= (?, 224, 224, 3) 
`allow_smaller_final_batch=False`: Tensor shape= (16, 224, 224, 3)

This is giving me an error downstream.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    467     try:
--> 468       str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]
    469     except TypeError:

/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    467     try:
--> 468       str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]
    469     except TypeError:

/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py in as_bytes(bytes_or_text, encoding)
     64     raise TypeError('Expected binary or unicode string, got %r' %
---> 65                     (bytes_or_text,))
     66 

TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got None
...

TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'list'> to Tensor. Contents: [None, 1]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

How do I get the `batch_size` before I evaluate in `session`?

Answer (score 0):

`batch_size` is a hyper-parameter that you should assign to it, rather than a value to be evaluated in TensorFlow session, while there's not enough information to determine what trouble you encounter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking for clarification should be done via comments instead of by posting an answer. I'm aware that commenting requires a reputation score of 50. You might want to try answering questions that don't need clarification. You can also acquire reputation by asking well-received questions.